# how to make following pattern in php using nested for loop

Tags: php, design-patterns

I want to make matrix 512 columns x 256 rows, with the pattern like this as:

[image: expected result]

I was trying it with this one:

```
$b = 0;
matrik = [[]];
  for ($i=0; $i < 512; $i++) { 
     for ($j=0; $j < 256; $j++) { 
         if ($j=$b) {
             $matrik[$j][$j] = 1;
         }else{
             $matrik[$j][$j] = 0;
         }
         $b++;
      }
  }
return $matrik;
```

but output of this code was:

```
[
 [
   0
 ],
 {
   1: 1
 },
 {
   2: 1
 },
 {
   3: 1
 },
 {
   4: 1
 },
 {
   5: 1
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$matrix = [];

// For each row
for ($i = 0; $i < 512; $i++)
{
  // Current row
  $row = [];
  // Offset of the 1 in the row
  $offset = floor($i / 2);

  // For each column
  for ($j = 0; $j < 256; $j++)
  {    
    // If the current j is on the offset 1, else 0
    $row[] = (($j == $offset) ? 1 : 0);
  }

  // Append row to matrix
  $matrix[] = $row;
}
```